# esp32 WiFi connection issues

Tags: esp32

I'm a beginer with ESP32 programming.

I'm trying to play with the example provided in https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/wifi/getting_started/station/main and it works perfectly with my iPhone in tethering mode, however it's impossible to connect to my home access point.

```
I (776) wifi:mode : sta (30:c6:f7:29:c6:48)
I (776) wifi:enable tsf
I (786) wifi station: wifi_init_sta finished.
I (996) wifi:new:<1,0>, old:<1,0>, ap:<255,255>, sta:<1,0>, prof:1
I (1746) wifi:state: init -> auth (b0)
I (2746) wifi:state: auth -> init (200)
I (2746) wifi:new:<1,0>, old:<1,0>, ap:<255,255>, sta:<1,0>, prof:1
I (2756) wifi station: retry to connect to the AP
```

Each try fails. I tried to play with some parameters but nothing improves the situation. Any idea on how to collect more information to set the connection properly?

By the way I'm able to scan every visible network with https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/wifi/scan/main/scan.c so this is why I guess it's configuration related...

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue. I found that, for me, the issue was not in the ESP32. It was the WiFi Router. I had the security on the router set to 'WEP' in the router. When I changed the security to 'WPA2-PSK' the ESP32 device connected right away.